# javascript confirm value not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a confirm and alert message box.
both are getting displayed at the right time.

but in confirm box when i press cancel the applyaction_button_click is getting executed, which should not happen as i return false.

Similar is the case with alert box which returns false still applyaction_button_click is getting executed.

here is my code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                    ApplyAction_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ShowConfirm();");
}

   protected void ApplyAction_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Action to be applied
    }
```

JS function:

```
    function ShowConfirm() {
      //check if checkbox is checked if is checked then display confirm message else display alert message
      var frm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
      var flag = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++) {
          if (document.forms[0].elements[i].id.indexOf('Select_CheckBox') != -1) {
              if (document.forms[0].elements[i].checked) {
                  flag = true
              }
          }
      }

      if (flag == true) {
          if (confirm("Are you sure you want to proceed?") == true) {
              return true;
          }
          else {
              return false;
          }
      } else {
      alert('Please select at least Checkbox.')
      return false;
      }
  }
```

thanks

Comment: Just an aside: you can simplify your JS by saying `return confirm("...");` (instead of testing the confirm function's return value in the if statement).

Comment: yes this was it... how could i not see that.. sorry for the post

Comment: Wait, what? I wasn't saying your existing code was wrong - the bit I was talking about shouldn't be causing any problems - I was just saying you could simplify. The same applies with `if (flag==true)` - you can just say `if (flag)` (or `if (!flag)` if testing for false).

Comment: Maybe user175084 is saying the required fix was in the C# code, to say `ApplyAction_Button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "**return** ShowConfirm();");` (I nearly posted that as an answer in the first place, but although that's what you'd do with normal inline event handlers I don't actually know how that style of Asp.Net works so I didn't.)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a client side event on an asp server control that has a server event and both get triggered with the same action, returning true or false on the client doesn't stop it from executing its server event.

You could try to prevent the button's server event from executing by doing some kind of postback in your javascript code.

Comment: please..can you show me a postback for confirm cancel. thanks

Comment: @user175084 In asp.net, you can do a js postback with `__doPostBack(string EventTarget, string EventArgument);`. The EventTarget can help you determine what caused the postback in your server code